# SQL Server 2008 R2 Maintenance Plan - anything else?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-management

I have a number of SQL Server 2008 R2 databases that haven't had any maintenance plans run on them since birth, as my ISP's server provides a SQL Server version that doesn't have the Maintenance Plan option.

I've trawled through the numerous pointers, options, etc, but I just want to run something clean and simple on them. Having trawled, I've come up with the following simple T-SQL script:

```
USE dbname

ALTER INDEX ALL ON tablename1 REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80);
ALTER INDEX ALL ON tablename2 REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80);
etc etc for each tablename in a db

EXEC sp_updatestats;
```

That's it. None of the databases are bigger than 300MB each at the moment (probably a lot of bloatware in there already) and each one is backed up by another process so have I covered the bases?  Is there anything I've missed?

Regards

Tom

Comment: Better asked at http://dba.stackexchange.com.  That's where the DBAs mostly hang out.

Comment: also search for ola hallengren and you can run all of this with out any worries

Comment: Many thanks everybody.  Didn't know anything about this dba alternative.